# How to save a form into different tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new with laravel
I used the default Authentication and I added one other input that I wanted it to be saved on an other table how can I do that

Comment: Will you please explain the exact problem u have ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to save registration form input into different table (not to `users`) when user is registering, add something like this to `create()` method in `app\Http\Auth\RegisterController.php`:

```
Profile::create(['custom_column' => $data->custom_form_field]);
```

Comment: I want to save one input in table and the others on users table

Comment: @Nader that will do exactly what you want. Keep existing code in `create()` method as is and just add code from my answer after `User::create(....)` part.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation will be better to use connections in model. If this data is about user of course. Also there is important thing about submit method(simple submit or AJAX).

Comment: Could you please explain more ?

Comment: [Read Laravel official docs] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) about relationships - this is simplest way to understand it.